# AlertDialog onBackPressed executes function

Tags: android, android-volley, android-alertdialog

I have an android activity where on pressing a button user gets a confirmation alert box. On clicking confirmation we execute a function. Now i am facing a problem, when the ALert dialog is open and if we press BACK button...this function which should ony be executed on pressing confirm button gets executed. How can i avoid this?

```
     deliveredBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //alert
            new SweetAlertDialog(FinalActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Are you sure?")
                    .setContentText("Update status to DELIVERED!")
                    .setConfirmText("Yes!")
                    .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {

                            int i = 8;
                            String txtDel = "DELIVERED";
                            String doneStatus = String.valueOf(i);
                            changeDeliveryStatus(doneStatus, txtDel);
                            sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: You can probably add a check if the dialog `isShowing()` then `dismiss()` it else `show()` it.

Comment: You can handle the back button with `onBackPressed()` maybe ?

Comment: maybe on "WARNING_TYPE" sweetAlertDialog acts like confirmation when you dismiss it. you better checkout its source code.

Comment: Looks like a lib issue

Answer (score 0):

While I was checking out the library issues [as vuthaiduy1990 answer](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog/issues/140)

You can probably use

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);   
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);   
dialog.setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {   
        @Override   
        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {   
            dialog.dismiss();   
        }  
    });
```

Comment: I did not need to mention that but also need to add .setCancelClickListener(), and .showCancelButton(true) for this action